# Как работает ошибка IncompatibleTypes в java при восходящем преобразовании?

Tags: java, наследование, типы

Есть код:

```
public class A {    }
public class B extends A {    }

public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args){
        A a2 = new B();  //Восходящее преобразование.     
        B b1 = a2;       // Ошибка компилляции. IncompatibleTypes. Нельзя конвертировать А к B        
    }
}
```

**Вопросы:**  Из каких соображений ссылка типа `B` не хочет ссылаться на ссылку класса родителя, которая ведёт на объект класса `B`? И почему при записи `B b1 = (B)a2;` всё отлично приводится?

Comment: Подразумевается, где и на какой странице в оракл док писали об этом.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2

Comment: @zRrr а перевести и растолковать можете? Вы то похоже понимаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопросы: Из каких соображений ...

Из таких:

```
public class A {    }
public class B extends A {    }
public class B1 extends A {    }

public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args){
        A a2 = new B1();  //Восходящее преобразование.     
        B b = a2;       // Ошибка компилляции. IncompatibleTypes. Нельзя конвертировать А к B        
    }
}
```

На строчке

```
B b = a2;
```

компилятору нет дела до того, откуда взялась ссылка `а2`. Единственное, что можно сказать, это что за `а2` может скрываться как объект типа `А`, так и любой его наследник. И этот наследник совсем необязательно типа `В`.

Comment: не понял. Можно подробнее?

Comment: Ну в общем-то суть прояснилась, спасибо. Если в течении 20 часов никто не выскажется лучше, то ответ принят.